# Trying to delete a recently created div (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am trying to remove the #ajax-form upon a click of the delete button I have up there.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Javascript:

```
function deleteAddLinkBox() {
  $('.container-delete-button').on('click', function(event) {
       $('#ajax-form').remove();
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><div id="ajax-form"><h1>Submit a new link</h1>
<div class="container-delete-button">☒</div>
<form action="/links" method="post">    
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Url">
  </p>
etc....
```

Comment: call the function it will work

Comment: Is there any reason you have enclosed the `on()` method inside another function?

Comment: It doesn't :(
I call it here:
$(function() {
  animateLinks();
  addFavouritesHandler();
  prepareNewLinkHandler();
  deleteLinkOnClick();
  deleteAddLinkBox();
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(".container-delete-button")` finds elements with that class and binds to them. If elements don't have the class at the time the binding is made, the events will not be handled.

The on function allows you to get round this by handling them on another element when the event "bubbles up to" a parent element. In this instance, we could say the body element – there may be a more specific common parent you could choose.

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.container-delete-button', function(event) {
       $('#ajax-form').remove();
  });
```

Comment: You might want to explain why this works (when providing a selector as second argument to the `on` function, `on` works as `delegate`, and delegating events will work with dynamically created elements, whereas statically bound handlers won't)

Comment: added a simple description of the proble, hope it helps @EliasVanOotegem

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use this code inside the function

Try this

```
$('.container-delete-button').on('click', function(event) {
       $('#ajax-form').remove();
  });
```

if the button is dynamically created then try using the delegate

```
     $(document).on('click','.container-delete-button', function(event) {
       $('#ajax-form').remove();
  });
```